# What is the best way to build a page template in flutter

Tags: flutter, templates

Is there any kind of template builder for flutter (e.g. similar to jinja) or what is the best way to build a page template inside the app?

Answer (score 0):

Traditional template mechanisms provide a way to separate the static content (text, graphics etc) from the dynamic data at design time. At run time you provide the dynamic data and it is rendered in the template.

Flutter has no such concept - the whole display is rendered by widget code. But you can think of widget code as templates that render the run time data.

Comment: Thank you for shedding some light on the topic. I guess coming from css and html I'm going to need some time to get used to this idea.